# Проверка поля input на уже существующие данные

Tags: php, mysql, input

Сайт на php+mysql

Есть админчасть (самопись), в базе по товарам есть уникум поле Code, как организовать проверку ввода этого кода при добавлении товара, сразу после вставки значения? Это может аякс или какой jquery надо подключить? И выводить списки кодов всех. Или просто как-то обращаться к базе не перегружая страницу?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще проверкой называется валидация. В PHP есть свои встроенные типа проверка на корректность email. Старайтесь самопись делать в рамках MVC, а то потом будет тяжело разобраться. Можете валидацию повесить на кнопку Submit перед отправкой с помощью JS. Если функция пройдет все проверки возвращает True, тогда данные отправляйте с формы на PHP через Post/Get.

---

Для выборки данных без перезагрузки страницы можете использовать jQuery autocomplete
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Ну тут в плане не какого-то плэйсхолдера, а именно из перечня, например, если в базе есть коды 001 и 002, то при вводе таких кодов, чтоб загоралась надпись, что такой код уже есть в базе